# Tesseract read_params_file error

Tags: ubuntu, tesseract, python-tesseract

Trying to run tesseract from the terminal with

```
tesseract 1_clean2.png output -l eng -oem 1 -psm 11
```

and this is what I'm getting:

```
Tesseract Open Source OCR Engine v3.04.01 with Leptonica
read_params_file: Can't open 1
read_params_file: Can't open psm
read_params_file: Can't open 11
Detected 22 diacritics
```

The output is created, however i dont thing the config parameters are being applied.

Any idea what this might be?

Comment: You should use 2 '-' symbols instead of 1

Comment: @DmitriiZ. tesseract expects CLI to be given with only one '-'. Have you tried the '--' options? Throw errors in my case.

Comment: @NightFury13 Thanks for noting, see https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage . For the latest version you should use single `-` for language option and double `--` for oem and psm options

Answer (score 0):

As stated in [tesseract CLI wiki](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/Command-Line-Usage) you should use double dash for the ***oem*** and ***psm*** options.

```
   OCR options:
  --tessdata-dir PATH   Specify the location of tessdata path.
  --user-words PATH     Specify the location of user words file.
  --user-patterns PATH  Specify the location of user patterns file.
  -l LANG[+LANG]        Specify language(s) used for OCR.
  -c VAR=VALUE          Set value for config variables.
                        Multiple -c arguments are allowed.
  --psm NUM             Specify page segmentation mode.
  --oem NUM             Specify OCR Engine mode.
```

So in your case correct line would be

```
tesseract 1_clean2.png output -l eng --oem 1 --psm 11
```